# Setting KendoGrid dataSource dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Is there a way to set the dataSource using a string containing the data to display in a KendoGrid. Assuming the columns in data string matches the column definitions in the grid, I've attempted the line:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource ({ data: dataString });
```

where dataString is of the format "{ column1: value1, column2: value2 }" or "[ { column1: value1, column2, value2 } ]" followed by:

```
$(gridId).data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(ds);
```

to set new grid dataSource, however this approach is not working.

I can work around this by parsing the dataString into an object then adding this object to an array & using this array as the parameter for the data attribute when defining ds.

Is there a more efficient way to assign new data to a kendoGrid using a string containing the data to display?

Answer (score 2):

First convert string to JSON and after that, set grid's data source:

```
$('#gridId').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(JSON.parse(stringData));
```

Answer (score 0):

You  may have to invoke the read method once you set your datasource:

```
$(gridId).data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Hi kryptonkal thank you for your response & apologies for the delay in getting back to you. I've tried your suggestion & sadly I was unsuccessful, anymore suggestions would be appreciated.